# How to update a store in vuex from outside?

Tags: xamarin, vue.js, vuex, onsen-ui

I have an iOS app that needs to pass data to a vue front-end:

```
const customerStore = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    data: [
      { id:1, title: 'Foo' },
      { id:2, title: 'Bar' }
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    list (state, data) {
      state.data = data
    }
  }
})

const ListCustomersPage = {
  key: 'ListCustomersPage',
  template: '#ListCustomersPage',
  components: { toolbar, cellcustomer },
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Select Customer',
      items: customerStore.state.data
    }
  },
  methods: {
    push() {

    }
  }
};
```

However, I need to mutate the store from an injection on the webview:

```
web.InjectJavascriptAsync("customerStore.commit('list', [])").Start()
```

But the list is not changed. No error is shown when calling the injection.